# Position View above current layout but not above navigation bar and status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I was wondering is it possible to position View above current layout but not above navigation bar and status bar programmatically?

I have tried this:

```
MyView myView = new MyView(context)
ViewGroup root = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
root.addView(myView);
```

The good thing is that View is above everything but the bad thing is View is also above navigation bar and status bar so when I move it, it can go on top of them. I know I can make my layouts to be FrameLayouts but I don't want to do that and enforce all of them to be FrameLayouts.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: are you saying that it should be on top in terms of vertical alignment or in terms of who is showing currently on the screen

Comment: @Elltz, it should work something like `NavigationDrawer` or `Dialog`. I would like to create some View programmatically and then just show it on top of current layout like Dialog. It only shouldn't be on top of navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this

```
MyView myView = new MyView(context)
FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout)activity.getWindow()
        .getDecorView();//your decorview is a FrameLayout
root.addView(myView,0);//can add params
```

Edit

for the logic, first of all get the location of the navigation bar on the Screen by getting a reference to the navigation bar and calling `getLocationOnScreen(int[])` after if it is a `Dialog` or `PopupWindow` you can use `Gravity` to position it on top of the navigation bar because you have co-ordinates, but if it is a `View` you can use margins along with `Gravity` all in your `LayoutParams` to position it to your preferred location.

Lucid enough?

Comment: Hmm, thank you but how can I set it to be above navigation bar? I don't think I can fetch navigation bar and set a rule to position my View relatively of nav bar.